# MVC DataAnnotation Validation Language

Tags: validation, model-view-controller, data-annotations, globalization

I wanted to change the language of the error message of an invalid field, I managed to do that downloading the .NET language pack of my desired language and change the Culture in the code. The problem is that if I check in the project on the TFS, no changes are applied, because there are no references to the language pack, so if I run the application on another PC in which is not installed the language pack it will remain in english. Is there a way to import the language pack into the application?